# Form values won't store into my SQLite database, yet others will

Tags: database, html, sqlite, flask, request.form

I am building a dynamic form where my text fields store into two tables: quizzes and questions. The questions table has a foreign key to identify which quiz they belong to. However, while my questions store correctly into the questions table, the quiz information (year and title) won't store into my quizzes table. I have been studying the code for days but cannot figure out the problem.

This is the flask code:

```
def register_quiz():
try:
    print("register_quizzes")
    db=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    print(sqlite3.version)
    db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cursor = db.cursor()
    print("Title = " + request.form['title'])
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO quizzes (year, title) VALUES (?,?)''', (request.form['year'], request.form['title']))
    db.commit()
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

I create the table here

```
def create_quizzes():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quizzes
              (quizid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
              year INT, topic VARCHAR,
              title VARCHAR)''')
db.commit()
```

And this is the form code:

```
<fieldset id="field">
<legend>Quiz Storage</legend>
<tr>Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{request.form.title}}"></tr><br>
<p>Year: <select name="year" id="schoolyear" value="{{request.form.year}}">
     <option value="1">7</option>
     <option value="2">8</option>
     <option value="3">9</option>
     <option value="4">10</option>
     <option value="5">11</option>
     <option value="6">12</option>
     <option value="7">13</option></select></p>
```

Have I missed something or is there an error somewhere? Please, anything would help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be due to

1.) Foreign key issues not properly referenced

2.) triple single quotes in the sql queries

**Lets start with foreign key**

They are so things You will need to know.

Between **Questions** and **quizzes** which of the table is parents and which one is the child as you did not specify them.

A **parent table** is the table to be referenced while a **child table** is the table making the reference

Let assume that  Questions table is the parents and quizzes table is the child.

lets assume question table has a column called question_id an int

and  quizzes table has a column question_id which references question_id of the parents table(Questions)

To make an insert, You must first insert into the parents(Questions) before inserting on the child(Quizzes) this because of the question_id reference.

whenever you try to insert into quizzes table, it will check if that question_id already exists on the parents table before allowing insertion otherwise it will not insert.

This is because is what parents has it will give to the child.

If for example question_id of the parents table has a value of 1

then to insert into quizzes which is the child, the 
question_id of the quizzes table must have a value that corresponds with that from the parents and this case 1.

You will first try to insert directly into sqlite first and see that insertion is working on both parents(questions) and child(quizes) table before saying that the problem is from your flask code.

**solution 2**

if foreign key is not your issue, then

Why don't use **sql-alchemy** which is just simple and straight forward.

Again Why are you using triple single quotes in the sql queries. its often preferable to initialize form parametere before passing it into sql queries

something like

```
yr = request.form['year']
tit = request.form['title']
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO quizzes (year, title) VALUES (?,?)", (yr,tit))
```

so you can try this

```
def register_quiz():
try:

    yr = request.form['year']
    tit = request.form['title']

    print("register_quizzes")
    db=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    print(sqlite3.version)
    db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cursor = db.cursor()
    print("Title = " + request.form['title'])
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO quizzes (year, title) VALUES (?,?)", (yr,tit))
    db.commit()
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

alternatively. I have also re-written your code below to ensure work-ability. just change the db connection to reflect yours and make adjustment where neccessary
**html**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "{{ url_for('register_quiz') }}" method = "POST">
         <fieldset id="field">
<legend>Quiz Storage</legend>
<tr>Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{request.form.title}}"></tr><br>
<p>Year: <select name="year" id="schoolyear" value="{{request.form.year}}">
     <option value="1">7</option>
     <option value="2">8</option>
     <option value="3">9</option>
     <option value="4">10</option>
     <option value="5">11</option>
     <option value="6">12</option>
     <option value="7">13</option></select></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/register_quiz',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def register_quiz():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      try:
         yr = request.form['year']
         tit = request.form['title']


         with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO quizzes (year, title) 
               VALUES (?,?)",(yr,tit) )

            con.commit()
            msg = "quiz successfully added"
      except:
         con.rollback()
         msg = "error in insert operation"

      finally:
         #return render_template("result.html",msg = msg)
         return 'success'
         con.close()
```

Comment: my advice is remove those foreign key first and see if insertion will work directly from your sqlite or from your applications  before implementing foreign keys. Thanks